# static cast between pointers of inherited types

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, static-cast

I am trying to do this

```
static_cast<IntrusivePtr<B>>(IntrusivePtr<A>)
```

where B publicly derives from A. However this gives the error

```
invalid conversion from A* to B*
```

Can anyone explain to me the problem here? I can sort of get around it by doing

```
static_cast<B*>(IntrusivePtr<A>.get())
```

Which in theory is exactly what the above error message says is not allowed. This is on GCC 4.4.7

Comment: What is `IntrusivePtr`? The error message you say you get doesn't match the code you've given. Give a _complete_ example, which will help us to explain the nuances to you.

Comment: Wait, are you casting from a base *to* a derived class?

Comment: "*Which in theory is exactly what the above error message says is not allowed.*" The error message says that it cannot implicitly convert one type to the other. Which is true. `static_cast` can perform non-implicit conversions.

Comment: Are you at liberty to change `IntrusivePtr`?

Comment: @davmac the error message matches the code that *logically follows* from what's given.

Comment: IntrusivePtr is a slightly extended version of the boost intrusive ptr, I cannot change it significantly. Yes I am trying to cast from base to derived as I have a vector<base*> (which actually contains derived*) and I need to call a function which only exists on the derived class, I also can't easily change this vector to just be vector<derived*> so this seemed like an easy solution

Comment: The correct solution is probably to add the function to `base`.

Comment: gcc 4.4.7 is positively ancient.

Comment: @n.m. that may well indeed be the case, but it's certainly not clear from what's provided in the question.

Comment: @davmac I'm a sick man, I have suffered from 25 years of exposure to C++ (no joke) so I involuntarily recognize certain patterns...

Answer (score 6):

The concept you're looking for is called type **covariance** - you want `IntrusivePtr<T>` to be covariant on `T`, which means that `IntrusivePtr<D>` is a subtype of `IntrusivePtr<B>` if `D` is a subtype of `B`. There are languages whose type system supports this, C++ is not one of them.

In C++, `IntrusivePtr<A>` and `IntrusivePtr<B>` are completely unrelated types, regardless of what `A` and `B` are (unless they're the same type). If you want to support that conversion, you have to support it explicitly:

```
template <class T>
struct IntrusivePtr {
    template <class U, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value>>
    IntrusivePtr(IntrusivePtr<U> const& rhs) { ... }
};
```

or do what you're doing and side-step the `IntrusivePtr` class template.

---

In retrospect upon rereading the question, it seems more likely that `IntrusivePtr` supports the above conversion, but does an implicit cast between the two types - which is valid for derived-to-base but invalid for base-to-derived. But you can always explicitly cast from base-to-derived. That is:

```
struct B { };
struct D : B { };

B b;
D* d1 = &b;                  // error
D* d2 = static_cast<D*>(&b); // ok
```

Comment: @Bathsheba Though having reread the question, I think that OP's `IntrusivePtr` may support this conversion - and OP is just trying to do base to derived? Unsure.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that the IntrusivePtr wrappers would melt away and expose their raw pointers, which would then be the arguments to the static_cast, ie static_cast<B*>(A*)

Comment: @Madden That's not safe though - you have to *know* that it's a derived type. It's better to make the user to it explicitly than to silently break the type system.

Answer (score 1):

`IntrusivePtr<A>` and `IntrusivePtr<B>` are completely unrelated types. So you can't cast between them statically (unless `IntrusivePtr` contains explicit conversion code or `A` and `B` are the same).

And note that you can't statically cast from a base to a derived class.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. If there's a suitable conversion operator (and in this case there *should* be a suitable conversion operator *template*), `static_cast` will call it.

Comment: *you can't statically cast from a base to a derived class* -- surely you can, that's the basis of $1.6Bn/year CRTP industry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way how IntrusivePtr can be changed.

```
template <typename T>
struct IntrusivePtr {

    IntrusivePtr(const IntrusivePtr& other) {
         ... // do the refcounting
         ptr = other.ptr; // straight assignment, pointers are of the same type
    }

    template <typename Q,
       typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<Q*, T*>::value>>
    IntrusivePtr(const IntrusivePtr<Q>& other) {
        ... // do the refcounting
        ptr = other.ptr; // straight assignment, pointers are compatible
    }

    // this can only be used in explicit conversions
    template <typename Q,
       typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<T*, Q*>::value>>
    // must add bogus default parameter, or the compiler will complain
    explicit IntrusivePtr(const IntrusivePtr<Q>& other, int=0) {
        ... // do the refcounting
        ptr = static_cast<T*>(other.ptr); // explicit downcast, trust the programmer
    }
 ... // other methods

 T* ptr;

};
```

Checking:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

IntrusivePtr<A> a;
IntrusivePtr<B> b;

a = a; // ok, straight copy
a = b; // ok, implicit upcast
b = static_cast<IntrusivePtr<B>>(a); // ok, explicit downcast
b = a; // error, implicit conversion is not allowed
```

**However**, if IntrusivePtr is not too far off boost::intrusive_ptr, it should have a function similar to `boost::intrusive_ptr::static_pointer_cast`. Which probably should be used instead, especially with compilers that don't support C++11.